# Nested Queryrenders cause parent renderer to rerender with data returned from inner renderer

Tags: relayjs

Say i have a parent component (called Wrapper) that is a `QueryRenderer` that just fetches:

```
query productQuery {
   product {
      id
      name
   }
}
```

and then i have a `QueryRenderer` (that renders a component called Inner) that renders the following query:

```
query productInnerQuery {
   product {
      id
   }
}
```

what happens is that inside the outer component Wrapper gets subscribed to updates on product, causing it to rerenders with the `productInnerQuery` (name is undefined) when the page loads since that component loads on mount. what can i do so that this doesnt happen and that the the outer queryrenderer doesn't get affected by the inner one?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the re-render is caused by the store updating the record corresponding to the `product.id`. I don't know your exact use case but I believe you could: 1. refactor your hierarchy to use createRefetchContainer or 2. try aliasing your product in one of the queries. `innerProduct: product { id }`. Personally I'd go for #1 and #2 is just a guess

Comment: hey @hisa_py maybe you can help me out! im currently trying to refactor and use createRefetchContainer, but I'm coming into some barriers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647295/refetch-method-for-createrefetchcontainer-doesnt-execute-callback

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1843#issuecomment-378299074

Essentially:

> I recommend avoiding QueryRenderer inside QueryRenderer, the top one will rerender the below one in the tree causing another fetch