# Refetch method for createRefetchContainer doesn't execute callback

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern

My `QueryRenderer` uses the following Query:
```

```
graphql`
    query page_Query {
      viewer {
        id
        ...MountedRenderer_viewer
      }
    }
  `
```

and this is what my `createRefetchContainer` looks like:
```

```
createRefetchContainer(
  MountComponent,
  graphql`
    fragment MountedRenderer_viewer on User @argumentDefinitions(show: { type: "Boolean", defaultValue: false }) {
      id
      name @include(if: $show)

    }
  `,
  graphql`
    query OwnershipsRenderer_Query($show: Boolean!) {
      viewer {
        ...MountedRenderer_viewer @arguments(show: $show)
      }
    }
  `,
);
```

inside my `MountComponent` component I do this in componentDidMount:
```

```
this.props.relay.refetch(
        { show: true },
        err => {
            console.log('done!');
        },
        { force: true },
      );
```

I look into my store and I see that the data for "name" is fetched and merged with the store. However, the `MountComponent` does not get rerendered with the new data nor does it log "done". Shouldn't the `MountComponent` be subscribed to the viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the signature of `refetch` is `refetch(refetchVariables, renderVariable, observerOrCallback, options)` so your callback should be the third argument.

Comment: yeah, @jouerai you're passing the callback as the 2nd arg